# Acumatica Scan Move

Tags: c#, visual-studio, customization, acumatica, warehouse

I am trying to add an additional step when using the set qty button in Scan Move screen (AM302010). I would like to set a value to another field before the standard functionality that sets the qty after pressing the button. Upon looking in the source code, I can't seem to find which graph I should extend in order to customize the screen. I would also like to know how to override or where to override these scan functions in acumatica.

Thanks for answering.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF11Z.png)

Edit*

Sorry for not being clear.

In scan move screen, there is a set qty button. Which allows the user to enter the qty on the detail. What I would like to do is add an additional step before that. For example, before setting the qty in the scan field, i would like to make the input insert Qty scrapped first. So the sequence would be, Press set qty button, input scrapped qty, press enter (set qty scrapped value), input qty, press enter(set qty value). (the original is, press set qty button, input qty, press enter).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b892X.png)

I have already found which graph to extend. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzYue.png) Currently, I am having trouble trying to understand this new process for wms in acumatica 2022 R1. Is it possible to add the new step, or maybe add another button, as a workaround, in the header to achieve the goal?

Thanks again/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please do not [delete and repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74074961). There is so little information here that the same advice applies to this one. [Edit] your post with more information. I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I have edited the document. Hopefully, I am being clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before recommending the approach for your query, would like to suggest you to review the following community articles that explain about the new WMS architecture and how to override different methods in the same:

- https://community.acumatica.com/customization-and-development-72/how-to-customize-an-existing-screen-with-the-new-automated-warehouse-operations-engine-in-acumatica-erp-2021-r1-and-later-8029
- https://community.acumatica.com/customization-and-development-72/how-to-customize-the-new-automated-warehouse-operations-engine-in-acumatica-erp-2021-r1-and-later-barcode-driven-state-machine-architecture-8024

Based on your requirement, would like to suggest the below approach:

1. Create a new Scan extension for `ScanMove` graph as below:

   ```
   public class ScanMoveExtension : ScanMove.ScanExtension {}
   ```
2. Create a new `ScanCommand` for performing the required actions/changes by overriding `Process` method.
3. Override `DecorateScanMode` method and add the new command before adding `SetQtyCommand` as below:

   ```
      [PXOverride]
      public virtual ScanMode<ScanMove> DecorateScanMode(ScanMode<ScanMove> original, Func<ScanMode<ScanMove>, ScanMode<ScanMove>> base_DecorateScanMode)
   {
           var mode = base_DecorateScanMode(original);
       if (mode is ScanMaterial.MaterialMode materialMode)
       {
           mode
               .Intercept.CreateCommands.ByReplace(basis =>
                {
                  // modify the order of the commands added
                  // RemoveCommand, SetQtyCommand and ReleaseCommand
                  // add your logic before SetQtyCommand
           });
       }
     return mode;
   }
   ```

This should enable you to execute the steps before SetQty command is executed.